# Redirect when two strings are matched

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to make the url:

```
www.google.com/forum.php?fid=5
```

Redirect to:

```
www.google.com/new.php?fid=5
```

But also need it to keep everything else intact because for example the link can be:

```
www.google.com/forum.php?fid=5&sortby=asc
```

And need `sortby` portion to be there upon redirect.

What the redirect needs to do is look for `forumdisplay.php` and `fid=6` and when both are found in the same url it redirects to `blog.php` and removes `fid=6` but keeps any other parameters there.

I searched and found how to do it with one string but not two.

Also, what's the difference between redirect and rewrite?

This is related to MyBB forum software. I made a separate php file that uses `forumdisplay` but with a new name.

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Thanks. Looked into how to do markups but looks like staff beat me to editing my post.

Comment: Great +1 for taking your time to read the tour its very helpful and also help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite you could use a condition to verify the id and grab what comes after if anything:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forumdisplay.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fid=6(&.*|.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /blog.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What if the fid had to be 6 for the redirect to take effect? Would I replace (.*) with 6? And would that also keep any parameters that where there before? Thanks.

Comment: @iHydra Then you can use query string condition will write an example.

Comment: Ah. I see. Will try that when I get on my computer. (On mobile) Thanks.

Comment: @iHydra you can also use this site to try it out if u want to: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: I tried both methods but didn't work. The specific links are `www.fatalgamers.net/forumdisplay.php?fid=6`(START) and `www.fatalgamers.net/blog.php`(END). Not sure if that makes a difference since I properly modified the necessary links. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fid=6
RewriteRule ^/forumdisplay.php?fid=([0-9]+)&(.*) http://www.fatalgamers.net/b.php?$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @iHydra try the last example, have edit it for the above needs.

Comment: My host was down for upgrades and then the datacenter screwed up. My site just got back online and updated the .htaccess and works great. Thank you very much!